# Table column acting as table row

Tags: css, html-table, html-email

#### Below is the preview in chrome, just the way I want it to be. Perfect!

[image: Preview on chrome]

---

#### And this is the preview in Firefox with the bug.
Where 2nd [td] is going on to the next line.

[image: Firefox preview]

This is to be used as **email signature**.

To see the code, here is the live url : http://dgntesting.com/ryan/johnmarkham2/table.html

I Have tried all the ways, but still can't figure out the issue in Firefox.

Here is the code :--------------------------------------------

```
<table width="540" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border:0;border-spacing:0;">
    <tr>
        <td width="540" height="157" style="padding:0"><img width="540" src="http://dgntesting.com/ryan/johnmarkham2/img/logo-final.png" height="157" valign="top" style="margin:0;vertical-align:top;padding:0;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding:0;margin:0;border:0;" width="540">
            <table width="540" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;border:0;border-spacing:0;">
                <tr>
                    <td height="67" style="padding:0;border-width:0;vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;"><a href="https://www.jimsbuildinginspections.com.au/" style="padding:0;text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://dgntesting.com/ryan/johnmarkham2/img/bottom-left.png" width="368" height="67" valign="top" style="margin:0;padding:0;vertical-align:top;"></a></td>

                    <td height="67" style="padding:0;border-width:0;vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;"><a href="tel:131546" style="padding:0;text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://dgntesting.com/ryan/johnmarkham2/img/bottom-right.png" width="172" height="67" valign="top" style="margin:0;padding:0;vertical-align:top;"></a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Your help will be very much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: The td has display: inline-block. But can you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Remove display: inline-block from your  <td> and its working fine in firefox

Comment: Okay I have now used a minimal and complete code with a testing example. And your advise was correct. I was mis-guided over the internet to actually use inline-block to show it inline. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to remove the display `inline-block` form `td`.

```
<td style="padding:0;margin:0;border:0;" width="540">
                                <table width="540" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;border:0;border-spacing:0;">
                                    <tbody><tr>
                                        <td height="67" style="padding:0;border-width:0;vertical-align:top;"><a href="https://www.jimsbuildinginspections.com.au/" style="padding:0;text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://dgntesting.com/ryan/johnmarkham2/img/bottom-left.png" width="368" height="67" valign="top" style="margin:0;padding:0;vertical-align:top;"></a></td>

                                        <td height="67" style="padding:0;border-width:0;vertical-align:top;"><a href="tel:131546" style="padding:0;text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://dgntesting.com/ryan/johnmarkham2/img/bottom-right.png" width="172" height="67" valign="top" style="margin:0;padding:0;vertical-align:top;"></a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody></table>
                            </td>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however removing inline-block worked on ( http://dgntesting.com/ryan/johnmarkham2/table.html )
But when i removed it from the main page ( http://dgntesting.com/ryan/johnmarkham2 ) the problem is still there. Can you please look into this?

Comment: Yes sure Jasdeep

Comment: The first td still has inline-block. Remove it from all of them.

Comment: Oh yes you were right. Actually I updated the code but somehow the ftp file transfer failed and I thought the file was updated.
Thanks for your help :)